# How to export a global object in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store the email of the user once successfully signed in.

For this,

- Created a file `logged_user.js`
- Created a class `LoggedUser` and a single instance of it named `loggedUser`.
- Exported `loggedUser`.

I was assuming that where ever I am going to import `logged_user.js`, I am going to get that single instance only. But actually, I am getting a new instance.

**<logged_user.js>**

```
class LoggedUser{
    #email;
    #userExist;
    constructor(){
        this.#email = null;
        this.#userExist = false;
    }

    setUser(email){
        this.#email = email;
        this.#userExist = true;
    }

    resetUser(){
        this.#email = null;
        this.#userExist = true;
    }

    get userExist(){
        return this.#userExist;
    }

    get email(){
        return this.#email;
    }
}

const loggedUser = new LoggedUser();

export default loggedUser;
```

**Function handling signing in**

```
 async handleSingIn() {
    this.clearAlert();
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    if (this.validateEmailAndPassword()) {
      await signIn(this.state.emailInput, this.state.passwordInput)
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          this.showAlert("Signed In.", false);
          loggedUser.setUser(this.state.emailInput);
          window.location.href = "/adminPanel";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          switch (error.code) {
            case "auth/invalid-email":
              this.showAlert("Invalid email!");
              break;
            case "auth/wrong-password":
              this.showAlert("Wrong password!");
              break;
            case "auth/user-not-found":
              this.showAlert("User not found!");
              break;
            default:
              alert(error.message);
              this.showAlert("Something went wrong!");
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  }
```

Once the user signed in the route is switched from Login page to admin page. There I am trying to get access to that email but it comes out to be `null`.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const collegeName = await 
    await getCollegeName(loggedUser.email);
    this.setState({collegeName: collegeName})
  }
```

I want only a single instance of `LoggedUser` to be imported throughout all the files.

Comment: This is not the way React works, you will need do the state management either by using context or by using a third tool library like redux.

Comment: loggedUser  is a single instance, why you think its dont?

Comment: @WistonCoronell not true

Comment: @DennisVash once user signed in successfully I am calling function ```setUser``` to store the email but when I am trying to get that email in another file I am getting ```null```. Then I observe that constructor is being called two times.

Comment: @lexith won't he need to access the same object again? how would you achieve this if not through state management even component level or app level? I would like to learn more about react if you could show me please, perhaps there is something else I am missing here.

Comment: Please just create a reproducible example as expected [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is a singleton.

Comment: @DennisVash it's only a single instance if you call it once. Sounds like the OP is calling it again and again.

Comment: @DennisVash I added some information. Kindly check it.

Comment: Ok, upon seeing your edition, you have two options, either you make your loggedUser a custom hook or you will need to rely on saving the users elsewhere, like in a state management, backend or a cookie, I think you may be coming from angular where observer pattern is often used, but unless you implemented here, react is not going to provide the functionality out of the box. please read https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html again, use context/redux to save the user or use something to store/retrieve the user outside react

Comment: @DennisVash every time you import a component it is an instance of its own, unless this instance is share between components by the means of state management or context it will instantiate a new user inside that component, this is per design, imagine all the buttons sharing the same properties in react?

Comment: @WistonCoronell Thanks! I think context will work for me.

Comment: @WistonCoronell after trying a while I found out that it is because of the way I switch the page, using this line of code : ```window.location.href = "/adminPanel"```. If I am switching pages using Link component from react-router-dom lib then everything is working fine. Do you know how to do the same programmatically?

Comment: @WistonCoronell Yes he needs the same object again. But this is not about react or angular or whatever. A state is nothing more than a "normal" object. The moment you save it in the state of the component react just adds a ton of hooks and functionality to it. Redux does basically the same, just takes the details out of components. 
What he wants is a singleton. And that's just a pattern. What he does is correct (the ES6 way). 
But he uses a hard reload and expects the object to still be there but in that case his whole app reboots.

Comment: @AshutoshAswal Depends on your routing. E.g. if you're using `react-router` which uses `history` then you can do `history.push('/adminPanel')`

Answer (score 0):

`loggedUser` actually exported once. As per ECMA 2015 standard `export` is an idempotent operation. The real issue here is the lost of `this`. The simplest way to fix it it to use arrow functions for class methods:

```js
    class LoggedUser{
    #email;
    #userExist;
    constructor(){
        this.#email = null;
        this.#userExist = false;
    }

    setUser = (email) => {
        this.#email = email;
        this.#userExist = true;
    }

    resetUser = () => {
        this.#email = null;
        this.#userExist = true;
    }

    get userExist(){
        return this.#userExist;
    }

    get email(){
        return this.#email;
    }
}

const loggedUser = new LoggedUser();

export default loggedUser;
```

This is a generic JS mechanism that has nothing to do with React

Comment: tried your version of ```LoggedUser``` but still the same issue.